# How do I programmatically ping a website in Android

Tags: java, android, ping

I trying to make an app that can get ping of websites or ip address and show just ping number in a textview,im using this code for get ping:

```
public void fExecutarPing(View view){
        Editable host = edtIP.getText();


    try {
        String cmdPing = "ping -c 1 -w 1 "+host;
        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process p = r.exec(cmdPing);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String inputLinhe;


        while((inputLinhe = in.readLine())!= null){

            Toast.makeText(this, inputLinhe, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error: "+e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

this code just give me multi toast message like when you pinging in windows Command, but how can i just get ping number for example: 85

Answer (score 2):

I recommend use this library https://github.com/potterhsu/Pinger

**Setup**
1. In root build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
    ...
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
  }
}
```

2. In target module build.gradle

   `dependencies {
      compile 'com.github.potterhsu:Pinger:v1.1'
   }`

Usage
1. Ping directly in synchronization:

```
Pinger pinger = new Pinger();
pinger.ping("8.8.8.8", 3);
```

2. Ping in asynchronization until it is succeeded:

```
Pinger pinger = new Pinger();
pinger.setOnPingListener(new Pinger.OnPingListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPingSuccess() { ... }

    @Override
    public void onPingFailure() { ... }

    @Override
    public void onPingFinish() { ... }
});
pinger.pingUntilSucceeded("8.8.8.8", 5000);
```

3. Ping in asynchronization until it is failed:

```
Pinger pinger = new Pinger();
pinger.setOnPingListener(new Pinger.OnPingListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPingSuccess() { ... }

    @Override
    public void onPingFailure() { ... }

    @Override
    public void onPingFinish() { ... }
});
pinger.pingUntilFailed("8.8.8.8", 5000);
```

Comment: Not working with ipv6

Answer (score 1):

[icmp4a](https://github.com/marsounjan/icmp4a) (my library) is another library which allows you do this on Android.
It should be more effective since it doesn't rely on launching another Process and running `ping` command in it.
It does ICMP ping directly in kotlin code.

Example:

1. **Get the library**

```
implementation "com.marsounjan:icmp4a:1.0.0"
```

2. **Single ICMP Ping**

```
val icmp = Icmp4a()
val host = "google.com"
try {
  val status = icmp.ping( host = "8.8.8.8")
  val result = status.result
  when (result) {
    is Icmp.PingResult.Success -> Log.d("ICMP", "$host(${status.ip.hostAddress}) ${result.packetSize} bytes - ${result.ms} ms")
    is Icmp.PingResult.Failed -> Log.d("ICMP", "$host(${status.ip.hostAddress}) Failed: ${result.message}")
  }
} catch (error: Icmp.Error.UnknownHost) {
  Log.d("ICMP", "Unknown host $host")
}
```

Logcat output

```
2024-01-26 16:22:48.515 ICMP D  google.com(8.8.8.8) 64 bytes - 12 ms
```

3. **Multiple ICMP Pings with specified interval**

```
val icmp = Icmp4a()
val host = "google.com"
try {
  icmp.pingInterval(
      "8.8.8.8",
      count = 5,
      intervalMillis = 1000
  )
    .onEach { status ->
        val result = status.result
        when (result) {
          is Icmp.PingResult.Success -> Log.d("ICMP", "$host(${status.ip.hostAddress}) ${result.packetSize} bytes - ${result.ms} ms")
          is Icmp.PingResult.Failed -> Log.d("ICMP", "$host(${status.ip.hostAddress}) Failed: ${result.message}")
        }
    }
      .launchIn(viewModelScope)
} catch (error: Icmp.Error.UnknownHost) {
  Log.d("ICMP", "Unknown host $host")
}
```

Logcat output

```
2024-01-26 16:29:16.633 ICMP D  google.com(8.8.8.8) 64 bytes - 15 ms
2024-01-26 16:29:17.577 ICMP D  google.com(8.8.8.8) 64 bytes - 17 ms
2024-01-26 16:29:18.598 ICMP D  google.com(8.8.8.8) 64 bytes - 17 ms
2024-01-26 16:29:19.614 ICMP D  google.com(8.8.8.8) 64 bytes - 15 ms
2024-01-26 16:29:20.630 ICMP D  google.com(8.8.8.8) 64 bytes - 13 ms
```